# How to increase the Until Activity timeout to more than 7 days in Azure Data factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

How to increase the Until Activity time to more than 7 days in Azure Data factory**strong text**

Comment: Please do not use the tag [azure-pipelines] for questions related to Azure Data Factory pipelines. [azure-pipelines] is for questions related to Microsoft's Azure DevOps pipelines feature.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

you cannot make it more than 7 days.

Comment: Is there any other approach do you have any idea

Comment: unfortunately there is no out of box functionality to handle it. what you can do is create a custom logic wherein in case if this untill activity fails, get the error message. Use if activity to compare the error message is w.r.t time out. If yes, than again call the untill activity

Answer (score 0):

I will be very interersted to know the use case that you need an untill with 7 days timeout , please elaborate .
I could have explored a foreach loop with a wait command .I suggest using the range function .

```
@range(1, maxNum)
```